# Xdebug not working when executing a Symfony console command in Homestead

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, symfony4, homestead

When executing `bin/console cache:clear` the debugger won't stop on the first line of code.

The following output is shown in the xdebug log.

```
[18806] Log opened at 2019-02-04 15:58:42
[18806] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[18806] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[18806] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[18806] W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000. :-|
[18806] I: Connected to client. :-)
[18806] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///home/vagrant/projects/valkplanner2/bin/console" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.0RC3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="18806" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.7.0beta1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
[18806]
```

I am using PhpStorm 2018.3.3.
The following is my debug configuration in PhpStorm:
[image]

And this is the Xdebug configuration in `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini`.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_log="/home/vagrant/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.collect_params=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
;use `route -n` to find dev machine IP address from homestead environment (seems to default to 10.0.2.2)
xdebug.remote_host="10.0.2.2"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir='/home/vagrant/profile'
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

The debugger works just fine when I do a request with the browser or Postman using the `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` in the URL or the Chrome debugger addon.

The log suggests communication with xdebug works, but PhpStorm does not react.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Change Xdebug port to 9001 (or some another number from default 9000). You may be connecting to some another service and not PhpStorm (e.g. php-fpm is the one that listens on TCP 9000 port as well on Mac/Linux and is the typical cause for "debugging does not work"); use `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` to check who is listening that port on a computer/OS where PhpStorm is running (on Mac PhpStorm cannot detect that port is already used).

Comment: *"The log suggests communication with xdebug works, but PhpStorm does not react."* Your log is incomplete/truncated ... so it can be anything.

Comment: Thank you very much, php-fpm was listening on port 9000 aswel as phpstorm. I changed the port to 9001 and now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like another service listening on Xdebug port instead of PhpStorm.

On Mac, PhpStorm cannot detect if Xdebug port is already used by another service or not (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29443).

You may use `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` sort of command to see what that service might be. Most likely it will be **php-fpm** (as it uses TCP 9000 port by default). On Mac & Linux, php-fpm quite likely will be installed on your dev machine (usually gets installed together with PHP).

**Solution:** change Xdebug port from default `9000` to some another port, most often it would be just next one -- `9001`. Do it in both php.ini and PhpStorm (make sure that it's not listening to debug connections at that moment; if it does, stop and start again). If you are using some webserver (e.g. Apache) you may need to restart that as well (for PHP to read new config).